# Showing TimeSpan With Hours:Minutes Format. Ex- (72:59)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written this piece of code to get the time span between two date time:

```
private TimeSpan CalculateTimeDifference()
{
    string StartDate = txtOffBarDate.Text;
    string StartTime = txtOffbarTime.Text;

    DateTime StartDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate + " " + StartTime);

    string EndDate = txtOnBarDate.Text;
    string EndTime = txtOnBarTime.Text;

    DateTime EndDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate + " " + EndTime);

    TimeSpan TotalTime = StartDateTime.Subtract(EndDateTime);
    return TotalTime ;
}
```

Now i want to store my time span result in a variable with 00:00 format (Hours:minutes).Please guide me how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) and [`Minutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties:

```
double hours = TotalTime.TotalHours;
int minutes  = TotalTime.Minutes;
string result = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int) hours, minutes);
```

However, i wouldn't use the string to store these informations at all. Use the `TimeSpan` since it includes all informations and convert it to a string only when you want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Use TotalHours, and ToString() method with a format:

If your TimeSpan is **less than one day(24 hours)**, use this simple:

```
string result = TotalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

If not, use this:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)TotalTime.TotalHours, TotalTime.Minutes);
```

Comment: This would actually return "00:59" since 72 hours and 59 minutes are actually equal to 3 days 0 hours and 59 minutes.